# Cannot run python script on crontab

Tags: python, bash, cron, spotify, spotipy

I am trying to run a bash script on crontab to execute a python script. The bash script contains an echo commant that writes to a log file and a command to run the python script. I see that the log is updated but the python script doesn't run.
I have tried `chmod a+x autoplaylist.py`, `chmod a+x jobs.sh`.
Here's my code:

jobs.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo $(date) Running jobs.sh
python3 /home/aprabhu3/repos/Autoplaylist/autoplaylist.py
```

crontab

```
* * * * * /home/aprabhu3/repos/Autoplaylist/jobs.sh
```

These are the modules I'm using in my python script `autoplaylist.py`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
import json
import re
import datetime
```

Comment: Typo.  The third line of your `jobs.sh` script is missing a leading slash, and is missing a space after `.../python3`.  You don't technically need the whole path to `python3`, since `/usr/bin` is in the PATH for a cron job.  Are you aware that's going to run every minute of every hour of every day, 1440 times a day?

Comment: Hi Tim, I made a mistake while typing the question. I corrected my post. I've been running it every minute just for testing. The plan is to run it hourly. Removing usr/bin still doesn't work for me.

Comment: Is this in your user crontab, or in the system crontab?  Have you tried adding `print('Hello 1')` at the very beginning of the file to prove that it's running?  Does it run if you type `./jobs.sh` at a command line?

Comment: It's a user crontab. I tried `sudo crontab -e` as well. Yes, `jobs.sh` works from command line.

Comment: Could it be the modules I'm using that's causing the problem? `spotipy.oauth2` requires accessing environment variables.

Comment: Almost certainly, yes.  You can set environment variables in your crontab (although all your cron jobs will see them), or in the `jobs.sh`, or even in the Python code by doing `os.environ['XXXX'] = 'yyyy'`.

Comment: Thanks Tim, it was the environment variables. I guess crontab connot find the environment variables unless I export them again in jobs.sh.

Comment: If you need environment variables, you have to set them (for instance, inside jobs.sh). Environment variables don't spring into existence magically. They are explicitly set in some place and then inherited to the child porcesses.

Comment: `cron` is never a good solution to periodic tasks and cannot be properly monitored, sandboxed, inspected w.r.t. job status and logs, or configured to depend on / provide dependencies for other system components. Use `systemd` `.timer` units instead, which have no such shortcomings. Then e.g. `journalctl --user -u autoplaylist.service` would show you what exactly happened to Python each time `autoplaylist.timer` fired.